# stack trace if i use ajax(jquery)

Tags: asp.net, stack-trace

Stack trace is a list of the method calls that the application was in the middle of when an Exception was thrown.
How can i obtain stack trace if i use ajax(jquery) to access to it.

```
function loadCompFilterTreeInfo() {
        var d = "";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: '<%=HandlerUrl%>',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                d = data;
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('<%= Resources.Resource.ErrorRequestingDataFromServer%>');
            }
        });
        return d;
    };
```

In my case occurs alert.

Comment: Run in DEBUG mode and add a breakpoint in the method: the exception details are not returned to the browser.

Comment: I want to get stack trace of server

Comment: Stack traces are not returned to the browser by default [for security reasons](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/is-a-stack-trace-of-a-server-application-a-vulnerability)

Comment: Is it possible to change   somewhere setting to get stack trace?

Comment: You would have to change the server code to return it in the response

Comment: Can give an example?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two layers that are interacting with each other

- Client
- Server

Your Javascript code runs on the client-side, but it's making an AJAX call to a resource that is on the server-side of things.

In this situation, if you are getting an error, it's because the server has encountered an error with processing the request.  If the server throws the error, you should be able to catch the error and display it in your 'error' event:

```
error: function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) {
    alert('Error Thrown: ' + errorThrown);
}
```

Also, assuming you have some sort of error logging on the server, you can check your server-side error log for any errors that may have occurred.